# How to check duplicate value inside foreach loop

Tags: php

I have 3 array like this from foreach loop

```php
$link = 'https://example.com/page/';
$parse = explode('/', $link);
for ($i = 0;$i <= 5;$i++)
{
    if($i > 0) {
        $link = $parse[0]."//".$parse[1]."/".$parse[2]."/".$parse[3]."/".$parse[4].$i;
        $get[$i] = curl($link);
        $re = '/class="img-lazy" src="(.*?)"/m';
        preg_match_all($re, $get[$i], $matches);
        foreach ($matches[1] as $content)
            {
                echo $content. "\r\n";
            }
    }
}
```

(loop from each page eg: example.com/page/1 will contain the array below and so on with page 2/3...)

Result:

```php
Array (Page 1)
(
    [0] => https://example.com/img1.jpg
    [1] => https://example.com/img2.jpg

)
Array (Page 2)
(
    [0] => https://example.com/img3.jpg
    [1] => https://example.com/img4.jpg

)
Array (Page 3 nonexist auto redirect to page 1)
(
    [0] => https://example.com/img1.jpg
    [1] => https://example.com/img2.jpg

)
```

The last one is duplicate. How do i remove it ?

I already tried to merge the array and array_unique function. But the duplicate one still there.

Comment: _"Page 3 nonexist so return to page 1"_, so why can't you just _not_ return page 1 for non-existing pages?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The page auto redirect to page 1 and my code keep getting the first page. I updated the link,please take a look !

Comment: avoid nonexist page in array so u can avoid duplicate value , or simply use a if condition to check

Comment: I did try if(strcasecmp($link,$link2==-2)) Keep looping then elseif (strcasecmp($link,$link2==0)) exit

Comment: Give it a  try `$all_array = (array) $matches[1];`. Add $all_array into my function.

Comment: It cant be done like this. Cause every page is different Array and it generate from foreach loop. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick solution run for loop only 5 times if loop is dynamic follow this answer

What I did is compare very first link. if it repeat then exit.
I checked and it works fine

your images are nice :-)

```
$get = array();
$firstcompare = 0;              
$firsttime = 1;
for ($i = 0;$i <= 17;$i++)
{
    if($i > 0) {
        $dup = $res = [];
        $link = $parse[0]."//".$parse[1]."/".$parse[2]."/".$parse[3]."/".$parse[4].$i;
        $get[$i] = curl($link);
        $re = '/class="aligncenter" src="(.*?)"/m';
        preg_match_all($re, $get[$i], $matches);
        if($firsttime){
            $stringlink = $matches[1][0];
            $firsttime = 0;
        }       
        foreach ($matches[1] as $content)
        {       
            if($firstcompare){
                if ($stringlink==$content) {
                    exit;
                }else{
                    // echo $content."\n\n";
                    echo "<img src=' $content ' /> " . "\r\n";
                }
            }else{
                    // echo $content."\n\n";
                    $firstcompare = 1;              
                    echo "<img src=' $content ' /> " . "\r\n";              
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Enuma Can you echo `$link` check on every loop, is all image exist in server? I have another solution but before that I wanna know where its happening[`Page 3 nonexist auto redirect to page 1`] exactly. Also show me the content for `$matches[1]`

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you very much Rasa ;) Ye these images are nice haha

Answer (score 1):

You may try like this as per yourArray, hope it will help you

Using Foreach:

```
$dup = $res = [];
foreach($yourArray as $arr){
    $imploded = @implode(',',$arr);
    if(!in_array($imploded, $dup)){
        $dup[] = $imploded;
        $res[] = $arr;
    }
}
```

(or)

Using Array Function:

```
$unique = array_unique(array_map(function($arr){ 
    return @implode(',',$arr); 
}, $yourArray));
$mapped = array_map(function($a){ 
    return @explode(',', $a); 
}, $unique_data);
```

Comment: I did give it a try but not working as i expected. The duplicate result still there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand everything but to remove duplicate data inside an array you can use the `array_unique()` function.

```
foreach(array_unique($yourArray) as $value):
   // Code goes here
endforeach;
```

It takes the array and return the clean one
https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php

Comment: I already give it a try but the array is seperate. Not one array

Comment: Note : Note that array_unique () does not work with multi-dimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to remove duplicate values from the multi-dimensional array by using PHP or Laravel.

> **Solution:**

```
$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

---

```
$input = Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => abc
        [1] => def
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [0] => ghi
        [1] => jkl
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => mno
        [1] => pql
    )

)



$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input)));
```

> **Output :**

```
 Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => abc
            [1] => def
        )

        [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ghi
            [1] => jkl
        )

        [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => mno
            [1] => pql
        )

        [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => ghi
            [1] => jkl
        )

        [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => mno
            [1] => pql
        )

    )
```

Comment: The array is from each page i used preg_match_all to get it. Its not like this. Its only `Array
(
    [0] => https://example.com/img1.jpg
    [1] => https://example.com/img2.jpg
Array
(
    [0] => https://example.com/img3.jpg
    [1] => https://example.com/img4.jpg

)`

Comment: @Enuma This is only array. This is the input & output look like. array(array('1' => 1, '2' => 2)). Just try my solution, it will solve your issue.  `$input = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $your_array)));`  In this just replace `$your_array` with your array variable

Comment: I did replace it with $matches[1] but still the same..result